# Knockout Mapping Plugin - how to add properties to the default mapping?

Tags: knockout.js

I originally had a viewModel like this:

```
var ObjectViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    //debugger;
    self.id = data.id;
    self.details = data.details;
    self.children = ko.observableArray(data.children);

    self.deleteChild = function (child) {
        // Pending UI
        // call API here
        // On success, complete
        self.children.remove(child);
    }.bind(self);

};
```

Now I'm trying to use the mapping plugin so I can make the children array elements observables.  I've done this:

```
var ObjectViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

But I'm not sure how to add the deleteChild method to this.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer here:

[Adding properties to the view model created by using the Knockout JS mapping plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673928/adding-properties-to-the-view-model-created-by-using-the-knockout-js-mapping-plu)

Basically, for each of the additional properties I need to add, I define a new property on innerModel like so:

```
var mapping = {
    create: function(options) {
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        innerModel.AdditionalProperty = 'Add Function Here';
        return innerModel;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I've accomplished this in a different way that seems to work as well.

```
function ObjectViewModel(viewModel) {
    var self = this;

    // bind the vm to self
    ko.utils.extend(self, viewModel);

    self.deleteChild = function (child) {
        // Pending UI
        // call API here
        // On success, complete
        self.children.remove(child);
    }.bind(self);
};

var model = new ObjectViewModel(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
```

Comment: Clever. I like this answer.