# Ignore properties on knockout viewmodel when serialized from aspnetmvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm having an ASPNET mvc site hvere the views has viewmodels with knockout. I'm trying to serialize the model passed to the view into the views viewmodel.

The model is passed to the with like standard aspnet mvc

```
@model Client.Controllers.TripDto
```

And the knockout viewmodel created using KO mappings is done like

```
        var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))';
        var mvcModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel);
        var viewModel = new TripViewModel();
        var mapping = {
            'ignore': ["expenses"]
        };
        ko.mapping.fromJS(mvcModel, mapping, viewModel);

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I have a property expenses on the KO "custom" viewmodel. The issue is that this property is not in the MVC model, but just a property that gets its data later.
But so far I haven't been able to pass the model into the viewmodel with out an error

> Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: expenses is not defined; Bindings value: foreach: expenses
>   [Break On This Error]

return new Function("$context", "$element", functionBody);

I'm a bit unsure if it really is the mapping that fails, but so far unable to see any uther possible errors.

So the question is, is it possible to use KO mappings where not all propertes are present in the model I'm mapping from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to use KO mappings where not all properties are present
>   in the model I'm mapping from?

I think KO mappings dose not care about this, but the models cares. As you call `ko.applyBindings` KO 'll search for the property associated with the HTML element, so if you are going to use property in HTML element `data-bind='id: property'` then this property must exist in your View-Model. But if it was null then it's OK.

Simply you need to extend your view model so include the new property `expenses` with default value like `null`

```
var mapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        //customize at the root level.  
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);

        innerModel.expenses= null;

        return innerModel;
    }
}
```

Kindly check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673928/adding-properties-to-the-view-model-created-by-using-the-knockout-js-mapping-plu)

Comment: Thanks, the property is already defined in the custom viewmodel as self.expenses = ko.observableArray();

Comment: I had a similar problem and used underscore.js to set up default empty arrays/objects so that the mapping plugin wouldn't freak.  Happy to provide link to example if required.

Comment: Actual my problem was related to lazy loading and is now using this approach. But thanks for the info about create!