# adding new properties to view model after applybinding in knockout js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am not so good at knockout js so i might have missed something.

My use case :

I have a simple view model.My page looks like this

```
     <body>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <label for="">
            Basic :</label>
      <input type="text" name="" data-bind="value: basic" id="txtBasic" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="">
            HRA :</label>
      <input type="text" name="" data-bind="value: hra" id="txtHra" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style="background-color:silver;">
        <hr />
        <label for="">
          <input type="button" data-bind="click : generateModelValue" value="Generate Runtime Property" />
          <input type="button" data-bind="click : tryRebind" value="Try Rebinding with clean node" />
<br>
                DA :</label>
         <input type="text" name="" id="txtDa" data-bind="value: $data.da"><br><br></div>

      </div> 
      <hr />
      <div>
        <label for="">
                Tax :</label>
        <input type="range" name="" id="rangeTax" min="0" max="30" value="0" data-bind="value: tax" />
        <span id="spanTax">[Tax%]</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="btnCalculate" data-bind="click: computeSalary" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div id="divResult" data-bind="text: salary">
                [Salary]</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>

            myViewModel={
                basic: ko.observable(1000),
                hra: ko.observable(10),

                tax: ko.observable(10),
                salary: ko.observable('Yet to be calculated'),
                computeSalary: function () {
                    this.salary(this.basic()+this.da()+this.hra());
                },
                generateModelValue: function () {
                  debugger;
                    this.da=ko.observable("123");
                },
                tryRebind: function () {
                  debugger;
                  alert("Why do i have to call this to update the view model");
                    ko.cleanNode($('body')[0]);
                    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel,$('body')[0]);
                }
            };

            ko.applyBindings(myViewModel,$('body')[0]);


        </script>
  </body>
```

I want to add a property at runtime (say in this case "da").So for making th example simple to read I will call the "**generateModelValue**" function on my model which will add a "**da**" property on "**myViewModel**" with a sample value "123".

This successfully creates a new observable property(i checked with console.log). **But doesnt update the UI**.

So after this click i have called another function on my view model that will try to do a **ko.cleanNode($('body')[0])** follwed by a **ko.applyBindings(myViewModel,$('body')[0]);** which then updates the UI.

---

**My Question :**

Do i have to call the clean node or there is some better way possible to update the UI as soon as the viewmodel is updated ?

**My Doubts :**

1. I dont think using clean node is a good way to achieve this ?
2. Would it cause any performance issues in case the object is too complex or big in size.
3. I am using
       `"<input type="text" name="" id="txtDa" data-bind="value: $data.da">"`
   in my HTML (so that undefined error is not thrown when i call applyBinding with the property not available in viewModel)
   is **$data really required** (any other alternative?)

**Posts Visited :** 
[Adding properties to the view model created by using the Knockout JS mapping plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673928/adding-properties-to-the-view-model-created-by-using-the-knockout-js-mapping-plu) 
( i am not so sure i understood this post. Would go over it again if recommended because i am too using the mapping plugin to convert the plain json response from AJAX calls to observable view model but my implementation is a bit different)

**Live Plunker :**
http://plnkr.co/edit/4EwSdKihVak1dGhuobbi?p=preview

---

**Edited :**
Why i need to achieve this-

Because at the time when I will call ko.applybinding my viewModel would always be **less than the data bind attributes required in my HTML markup** because of which undefined error would be thrown(i used $data to avoid this error).

so the final html view that would be passed inside the ko.applyBinding(html-element) would be a UNION of several smaller html snippets that would constitute the screen.

and it is not possible to gather all the view model properties at the time of calling apply binding because the complexity of the view model would increase with the user interactions(Ajax Calls)

I hope its clear.If not,I am creating a plunkr for the same. Would update soon.

**UPDATED**
New plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/8PNHk25jl2xig0GLyqQq?p=preview

In the above plunkr the section with

```
<div data-bind="visible: $data.da">
         You will see this section only if the da property is available on the view model
         </div>
```

will exist in the DOM at the time of applybinding but the **value of "da" will not**.
And after some user interactions view model would be updated because the object would receive new properties (such as da in tha above plunkr) through the ajax call. and hence the da section will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the way knockout is supposed to work. There are situations such as dynamic lists and the like where not all observables will be available immediately. However your observable is just a property on the model. This observable should be created along with `basic` and `hra`. There is no benefit to delaying it's creation.

Change your code to:

```
myViewModel = {
    basic: ko.observable(1000),
    hra: ko.observable(10),
    da: ko.observable(null),
```

If you want to signify that the value has not been set until the function `generateModeValue` then let `null` signify this or create another boolean observable which the function can set. For example:

```
myViewModel = {
    basic: ko.observable(1000),
    hra: ko.observable(10),
    da: ko.observable(null),
    daIsSet: ko.observable(false),
    ...
    generateModelValue: function () {
        debugger;
        this.da("123");
        this.daIsSet(true);
    },
    ...
```

Again, it is possible to dynamically add observables (using arrays or some other approaches) but this situation doesn't require that kind of functionality. Hopefully that clears some concepts up for you.

Comment: okay, i simplified my actual problem so that i could communicate it cleanly.
but the actual picture is much bigger. the solution has 2 sides( development and implementation)  the HTML template would always be there (its a union of -  say 4-5 different views) and its **not possible** to give nulls or empty models because attribute key values would be generated dynamically and by using jquery extend i will create the merged object with the desired properties - on the basis of which the dom would be shown.. if this is not clear i can edit my post with better description and a live plunkr

Comment: I'm not really sure your changes clear anything up. Are you curious why this doesn't work for purely academic reasons? I could explain that if you like. However as I've already stated the important lesson to take away here is that your approach is flawed and should be avoided.

Comment: @ankur - Your example is straddling two different approaches so I can't really tell what it is you're doing. You say the attribute key values are generated dynamically and that's fine. But your javascript functions have hard coded references to the "dynamic" key `da`. Here: `this.salary(this.basic()+this.da()+this.hra());` If `da` is dynamic then how do you expect the javascript to be updated to include other dynamic fields in the calculation?

Comment: kindly ignore the this.da() reference in the calculation . that was an oversight.

Comment: i have also updated my question with better explanation of the use case.Kindly have a look at it. thanks

Comment: kindly have a look at the question, i have updated it with a new plunkr. thanks.

Comment: @ankur - I'm not sure how much help I can be due to the fact that your use case is a lot more complicated than the question originally conveyed. However I will say this: Having the DOM point to ko observables that do not exist is *fundamentally* flawed and you need a different approach. You view should be a result of your model. If you need dynamic fields to be added you should create an array with a name, value and the HTML template to be used and dynamically add to it. Your view should then render the appropriate HTML for the fields as the respective properties are added.

Comment: Could you plz edit you answer to explain this 
"You view should be a result of your model. If you need dynamic fields to be added you should create an array with a name, value and the HTML template to be used". Also, what i am doing is create an extendable framework so that multiple teams can define their views separately , have a union of all that is required through an xml/json having view names and then finally depending on the data model received from the server ,parts of the DOM would be shown or hidden ( the worry is not about show/hide issues, the real intent is lot more complex).thnx

Comment: @ankur - Basically you would define an observable array in your model say `myDynamicFields` every dynamic field object would take the form of `{ value: ko.observable(), name: "da", template:"mytemplate.html" }`. Setup your view to iterate the observable array and display fields as you add them to the array. This would give you the dynamic functionality you need without requiring a complete rebind of your model.

Comment: thanks. but i dont think it would be possible for me to implement the structure you are advising.
I just want to ask that as far as i understand how knockout works(or perhaps any MVC) ->it scans the html and find data-bind attributes. so is dere any way to automatically create the empty/null based view model that could afterwards be sent to the applyBinding method.im just speculating . thanks for the help.

Comment: @ankur - There isn't anything built into Knockout that will do that *because you shouldn't have to*. Like I said, your solution is fundamentally flawed and you need to figure out another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a property at run time is going to require you to call apply bindings.

However, if you ware willing to part with your initial design, the answer is simple.

I am assuming that your salary components all have a common model that would allow you to derive how they would add to the salary computation.  Without the detail I am calling this the salary component.

```
  function salaryComponent(n,v,t){
       this.Name = ko.observable(n);
       this.Value = ko.observable(v);
       this.Type = ko.observable(t);
   }
```

If you need customized display by types, I would add a type descriptor to the salary component and then use

```
<div data-bind="foreach: salaryComponents">
    <!-- ko if: type() == 1 -->
       <data-bind="template: {name:'Da-template',data:$data}
   <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

to apply a template per salary component type in your array.  This will allow you to build snipets of html to represent each salary component.

So change your model to use an observable array to handle your dynamic model adds as follows:

```
   myViewModel={
            basic: ko.observable(1000),
            hra: ko.observable(10),

            tax: ko.observable(10),
            salary: ko.observable('Yet to be calculated'),
            //dynamic salary components 
            salaryComponents: ko.observableArray(),

            computedSalary = ko.computed(function(){
                var base = this.basic()+this.hra();
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(salaryComponents(), function(item) {
                    base+=item.Value()
                });
                return base;
            }
            generateModelValue: function () {
               salaryComponents.push(new salaryComponent('Da',123,1));
            },
        };
```

Using this design for your model allows multiple templates by salary type to create your complex UI display and allows you to add components to your view model that will not require you to call apply bindings again.

Oh and one last thing, there is no reason to have to call compute to determine salary.  Use a computed value instead:

```
  computedSalary = ko.computed(function(){
                var base = this.basic()+this.hra();
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(salaryComponents(), function(item) {
                    base+=item.Value()
                });
                return base;
   }
```

Again, not entirely sure this is what you were looking for based on how this was originally posted.

Comment: i dont think i fully understand... but as far as i could go 
//dynamic salary components 
salaryComponents: ko.observableArray(),

**this** would be a serious overhead because the data provider service now would have to generate the salary components array which seems vague when all they had to provide was an extra **da property** in the JSON.