# Knockoutjs treats input text as number

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using mapping plugin. I have a list of customer data. One of the properties is percent amount (int). However when I update the value of the text box the new percent property shows up as a string. How do I make it so that the mapping plugin updates percent property as an int.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could expose the field as a writable computed value:

```
var Model = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.percentProp = ko.observable();
  self.percentPropComputed = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return self.percentProp();
    },
    write: function(newValue) {
      if( !isNaN(newValue) ) {
        self.percentProp(parseInt(newValue));
      }
  });
};
```

html:

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: percentPropComputed" />
```

Comment: i have a list. and i'm using mapping plugin. How do I make it work with that?

Comment: instead of using the mapping plugin, you could define a model and do the adapting yourself. are you mapping json from an ajax call?

Comment: I want to use the plugin

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673928/adding-properties-to-the-view-model-created-by-using-the-knockout-js-mapping-plu