# Loading JSON data

Tags: knockout.js

I am unable to load JSON into observable array - there is no error, but array is still empty. JSON is parsed OK. self.selectedItems is array of objects with their own observable arrays and stuff. What am I doing wrong?

```
function VM()
{
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.loadData = function(){
        $.post("url", data, function(returnedData) {
            if (returnedData){
                var json = JSON.parse( returnedData );
                ko.mapping.fromJS( json, self.selectedItems );
            } else {
                alert("Error loading data");
            }
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Comment: Try using self.selectedItems as the 3rd parameter instead.  "ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self.selectedItems);"

Comment: I'm having error Unable to process binding which what seems it's child observable. I'm gonna see into it..

Comment: I've updated values manually and it works. It seems that nested observables are more complicated per [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673928/), and my model is not complicated enough to get too deep into it.

Comment: In the first line, you say array is empty, in the second line self.selectedItems has its own data. Can you please elaborate?

By the way, when are you calling loadData method?

Comment: List is starting empty and user adds items to it. loadData is called on button click, and selectedItems should fill. It fills nicely, except one of own properties is observable array which I assume makes problems.